# Unable to Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 (Legacy BIOS)

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, gpt

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12 / 14.04 (x86 & x64) alongside Windows 7.

I have a bootable USB stick and when I try to install Ubuntu there is no alongside Window` option **neither the Windows partition is seen by Ubuntu** in the something else option.

I know that many people had this problem and normally it's because of the partitions. However I checked and the partition is MBR and I have a Legacy BIOS (not UEFI).

I have made two extra partitions in Windows but when trying to install these don't appear (I tried to format them in NTFS, FAT32, swap, ext...) - it just appears a single partition with 500Gb free space, that corresponds to all disk.

The Question Is, How to Install Ubuntu along Windows?

Comment: There can only be 4 primary partitions. Have you reached this limit? Klick on "Try Ubuntu" after booting the live system, then open the dash any open GParted. It will show you your partitions.

Comment: You can also run this and copy & paste terminal output into above. `sudo parted -l`. You should not create partiitons with Windows, it knows nothing about Linux. And may convert to dynamic partitions which is Windows proprietary and does not work with Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Windows disk utility and make sure that it is a "basic disk".  If you create more than 4 primary partitions, it automatically converts to "dynamic disk", which Ubuntu doesn't support.  You will need to remove some partitions to get it back down to 4 in order to convert it back to a basic disk.